Размер шрифта в формулах docx
Нигде не могу найти как изменить размер шрифта в последней версии docx.js, помогите с решением, по умолчанию документ создаётся с 10 шрифтом в формулах, мне нужен 14 шрифт.
const paragraph33 = new Paragraph({
                    children: [
                        new Math({
                            children: [
                                new MathRun(`Std=${window.STD.Sj}+${vaValuesJ2[i]}×`),
                                new MathFraction({
                                    numerator: [new MathRun(`${optionT3_2}`)],
                                    denominator: [new MathRun("7.2")],

                                }),
                                new MathRun(`-${window.STD.L}-${window.STD.C}=${Number(window.jResult['J2'].std[`va${i + 1}`]).toFixed(2)}`),

                            ],
                        }),
                    ],
                });
                paragraphs.push(paragraph33);

